# CSS file not getting loaded on IE 10 and Google Chrome

Tags: html, css

I have just started learning html and css.

I have an html file "index.html" with code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="title">My App</div>
  <div class="app">
    <div class="screenshot">image1</div>
    <div class="description">text</div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I have a css file "style.css" file with code:

```
.description {
  color: red;
}
```

Both are in the same file location -

```
C:\Users\ravalesmita\Desktop\Portfolio\toplist\index.html
C:\Users\ravalesmita\Desktop\Portfolio\toplist\style.css
```

Using IE 10 and google chrome.

Expected: text should have red color when loaded on the browser.

Actual: text color doesn't change.

Can anyone point out why is the text within class description not showing red color?

Comment: Everything looks good, try hit the **reload** button on your browser.

Comment: It does not for me..I don't know whats the problem with my machine..Is it some setting for my browser?

Comment: I did save and hit the reload button. closed the browser and reloaded again.. Still the same

Comment: Did you post everything in style.css above?

Comment: yes, my code is simply 
    .description {
         color: red;
     }

Answer (score 0):

Have you saved the file previously in another folder, before you made a change to red? If so the browser may be reading that file instead of the one you are wanting it to. Try running it like this. If it works its not finding your css file for some reason.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.description {
color: red;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="title">My App</div>
<div class="app">
<div class="screenshot">image1</div>
<div class="description">text</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```